# NullInjectorError: No provider for ReducerManager

Tags: angular, ngrx-store, ngrx-store-4.0

I am using the new ngrx 5. This is the file that holds the reducers and the featureSelector:

```
import AppState from '../interfaces/app.state'
import { ActionReducerMap, createFeatureSelector } from '@ngrx/store'
import { partnerReducer } from './partner.reducer'

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = {
  partnerState: partnerReducer
}

export const getAppState = createFeatureSelector<AppState>('appState')
```

This is how I am importing the storeModule

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [...],
imports: [...
  RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES),
  StoreModule.forFeature('appState', reducers)
],
providers: [...],
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
entryComponents: [...]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

I have followed [this](https://toddmotto.com/ngrx-store-understanding-state-selectors) tutorial

When I run the app, I get the following error:

```
"StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[StoreFeatureModule -> ReducerManager]: 
\n  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[StoreFeatureModule -> ReducerManager]: 
\n    NullInjectorError: No provider for ReducerManager!"
```

But if I do provide ReducerManager in the providers, I get this error:

```
No provider for ReducerManagerDispatcher!
```

Comment: Did you add the ReducerManager to providers in app.module ?

Comment: yes, then I got the No provider for ReducerManagerDispatcher! error

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Managed to solve this by adding `StoreModule.forRoot({}),` in the imports.

> StoreModule.forRoot should only be called once in the root of your project NgModule. If you wan't to register a feature, use StoreModule.forFeature. Using forRoot registers the global providers needed for Store.

Check the github discussion [here](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/295) on this issue. The above reason was stated in the same discussion

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and I found this solution

```
imports: [
       StoreModule.forRoot({}), 
    StoreModule.forFeature('filter-app', filterReducer)
]
```

Comment: this is same as the answer below

Answer (score 0):

You also have to add

`EffectsModule.forRoot([]),`

in the root of your project NgModule

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35738584)

Comment: it does, you can check yourself, i had the same issue.