# Using NgRx (with ngrx-actions library) within an Angular 6 library

Tags: angular, angular6, ngrx, angular-library

I am trying to split up an Angular application with multiple modules into multiple (separate) Angular libraries (using [this guide](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-create-library)), so I can use these libraries within multiple Angular applications.
Currently the project has several modules, for example:

- One for authentication/authorization;
- One containing all kind of table components
- One containing all kind of filter components
- One containing all kind of chart components
- ... (I guess you get the point) ...

I started working on 'converting' the authentication/authorization module into a library, because I expected it would be the hardest and most complicated module.
Right now I am facing some problems which I will explain below.

The module (as it currently exists) makes use of NgRx in combination with ngrx-actions to reduce boilerplate.  Like mentioned (in [the guide](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-create-library)), a library and an app for testing the library are created. 
I copied all the contents of the existing module into the library folder.

Had to make some adjustments, because the existing module reads some constants from environment.ts and a global.ts which will (probably) not exist when it's used as a library.

Right now my folder structure looks like the following, to give some more context (removed the node_modules):

```
.
├── README.md
├── angular.json
├── e2e
│   ├── protractor.conf.js
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── app.e2e-spec.ts
│   │   └── app.po.ts
│   └── tsconfig.e2e.json
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── projects
│   ├── auth-lib
│   │   ├── karma.conf.js
│   │   ├── ng-package.json
│   │   ├── ng-package.prod.json
│   │   ├── package-lock.json
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   ├── src
│   │   │   ├── lib
│   │   │   │   ├── auth-check
│   │   │   │   │   ├── auth-check.component.html
│   │   │   │   │   └── auth-check.component.ts
│   │   │   │   ├── auth-guard.service.ts
│   │   │   │   ├── auth-routing.module.ts
│   │   │   │   ├── auth.module.ts
│   │   │   │   ├── auth.service.ts
│   │   │   │   ├── callback
│   │   │   │   │   ├── callback.component.ts
│   │   │   │   │   └── callback.html
│   │   │   │   ├── interceptors
│   │   │   │   │   └── auth.interceptor.ts
│   │   │   │   ├── permission-guard.service.ts
│   │   │   │   ├── signin
│   │   │   │   │   └── signin.component.ts
│   │   │   │   └── store
│   │   │   │       ├── auth-state.interface.ts
│   │   │   │       ├── auth.actions.ts
│   │   │   │       ├── auth.effects.ts
│   │   │   │       ├── auth.reducers.ts
│   │   │   │       └── auth.store.ts
│   │   │   ├── public_api.ts
│   │   │   └── test.ts
│   │   ├── tsconfig.lib.json
│   │   ├── tsconfig.spec.json
│   │   └── tslint.json
├── src
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── app.component.css
│   │   ├── app.component.html
│   │   ├── app.component.spec.ts
│   │   ├── app.component.ts
│   │   └── app.module.ts
│   ├── assets
│   ├── browserslist
│   ├── environments
│   │   ├── environment.prod.ts
│   │   └── environment.ts
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── karma.conf.js
│   ├── main.ts
│   ├── polyfills.ts
│   ├── styles.css
│   ├── test.ts
│   ├── tsconfig.app.json
│   ├── tsconfig.spec.json
│   └── tslint.json
├── tsconfig.json
└── tslint.json
```

public_api.ts is containing the following code:

```
/*
 * Public API Surface of auth-lib
 */

export * from './lib/auth.module';
export * from './lib/auth-guard.service';
export * from './lib/permission-guard.service';
export * from './lib/auth.service';
```

auth.module.ts contains the following code:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {SigninComponent} from './signin/signin.component';
import {AuthRoutingModule} from './auth-routing.module';
import {CallbackComponent} from './callback/callback.component';
import {AuthService, InternalAuthService} from './auth.service';
import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS} from '@angular/common/http';
import {AuthInterceptor} from './interceptors/auth.interceptor';
import {AuthEffects} from './store/auth.effects';
import {EffectsModule} from '@ngrx/effects';
import {AuthStore} from './store/auth.store';
import {AuthCheckComponent} from './auth-check/auth-check.component';
import {NgrxActionsModule} from 'ngrx-actions/dist';
import {StoreRouterConnectingModule} from '@ngrx/router-store';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SigninComponent,
    CallbackComponent,
    AuthCheckComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    AuthRoutingModule,
    NgrxActionsModule.forRoot({auth: AuthStore}),
    EffectsModule.forFeature([AuthEffects]),
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    InternalAuthService,
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true},
    StoreRouterConnectingModule,
  ],
  exports: [],
})
export class AuthModule {

}
```

**NOTE:** this is working when the module exists within a project (not as library).
FYI: The different components are dispatching some actions, like redirecting to the (Auth0) log in page.

Then.. when I want to import the AuthModule in the app.module.ts (the 'test application') I get the following error, which I can't solve.

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgrxActionsModule -> ReducerManager]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NgrxActionsModule -> ReducerManager]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ReducerManager!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:1062)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1244)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1141)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1244)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1141)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:8376)
    at _createClass (core.js:8429)
    at _createProviderInstance (core.js:8393)
```

I saw [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/295) and [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49127332/nullinjectorerror-no-provider-for-reducermanager), both suggesting the same answer, but they are not working in my case.

Is there someone who knows how to fix this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The suggestions in the Stack Overflow page and GitHub issue page I mentioned in my earlier post weren't enough to fix this problem, but helped me to 'solve' the problem or getting at least a bit further.

By importing the `StoreModule.forRoot({})` another exception will be thrown:

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AuthEffects -> Actions]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AuthEffects -> Actions]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Actions!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:1062)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1244)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1141)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1244)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1141)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:8376)
    at _createClass (core.js:8425)
    at _createProviderInstance (core.js:8393)
```

After importing `EffectsModule.forRoot([])` the following exception will be returned:

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[StoreRouterConnectingModule -> Router]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[StoreRouterConnectingModule -> Router]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Router!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:1062)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1244)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1141)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1244)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1141)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:8376)
    at _createClass (core.js:8425)
    at _createProviderInstance (core.js:8393)
```

By importing `RouterModule.forRoot([])` it will (finally) work!
My auth.module.ts is now looking like this:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {SigninComponent} from './signin/signin.component';
import {AuthRoutingModule} from './auth-routing.module';
import {CallbackComponent} from './callback/callback.component';
import {AuthService, InternalAuthService} from './auth.service';
import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS} from '@angular/common/http';
import {AuthInterceptor} from './interceptors/auth.interceptor';
import {AuthEffects} from './store/auth.effects';
import {EffectsModule} from '@ngrx/effects';
import {AuthCheckComponent} from './auth-check/auth-check.component';
import {StoreRouterConnectingModule} from '@ngrx/router-store';
import {StoreModule} from '@ngrx/store';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {NgrxActionsModule} from 'ngrx-actions/dist';
import {AuthStore} from './store/auth.store';
import {StoreDevtoolsModule} from '@ngrx/store-devtools';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SigninComponent,
    CallbackComponent,
    AuthCheckComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([]),
    AuthRoutingModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({}),
    NgrxActionsModule.forRoot({auth: AuthStore}),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
    EffectsModule.forFeature([AuthEffects]),
    StoreRouterConnectingModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    InternalAuthService,
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true},
  ],
  exports: [],
})
export class AuthModule {
}
```

One thing I have to test right now is if I will be able to add states and routes to the Angular application that's importing the auth library, because of importing multiple `forRoot` statements with an empty array in the library. I'll update this post after I have tested that!

Comment: I have the same goal as you. I want to use the store in my main app and also in other libraries but at the same time keeping the lazy-loaded mechanism. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `EffectsModule.forRoot()` to your test imports.

```
await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ YourComponent],
  imports: [EffectsModule.forRoot()]
})
```

as stated in here: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/187